# How do I pull specific attribute data from html elements using Guzzle PHP?

Tags: php, web-scraping, guzzle

I am trying to scrape specific information (the title of the novel, and the price) from a website (eg., the 'content' of a meta element).

I have already requested the html body, turned it into a string and used the evaluate() method to show the program where exactly I want to pull the data.

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    $client = new Client(); // Create a new client object
    $response = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.rightstufanime.com/category/Novels'); //grabs HTML data from website
    $htmlString = (string) $response->getBody(); //Grabs the body of the html, turns it into a string and assigns it to the 'htmlString' variable

    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc = new DOMDocument(); //Create a 'DOMDocument' object called 'doc'.
    $doc->loadHTML($htmlString); //Run the method and pass in the htmlString
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc); //Create a new DOMXPath object and pass in '$doc' as the constructor
    
    $titles = $xpath->evaluate("//div[@class=\"facets-items-collection-view-row\"]//div[@class=\"facets-items-collection-view-cell-span3\"]//div[@class=\"facets-item-cell-grid\"]/meta");
```

Also quick note: I'm very new to programming in general so I'm sorry if this is obvious to most of you

Edit: I sometimes add comments to explain code i learn so i understand it better so don't mind that lol

Comment: Ok...so what exactly is the issue?

Comment: @ADyson I dont know how to get the 'content=' attribute from the meta element. Basically i followed a tutorial and it didn't show how to do it. I checked the documentation, couldn't find anything on there. So i decided to ask here

Comment: A very important skill to practice is breaking down a problem into independent pieces. In this case, Guzzle is not relevant to the part of the problem you are working on - once you have the string of HTML in `$htmlString`, doesn't make any difference if it came from a web page, a file, or just a hard-coded test case in your code. In fact, a hard-coded test case is exactly what you should be working with here - a [mre] that both you and people helping you can use to test possible approaches to the problem.